# Securing a simple Linux server that holds a MySQL database?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

MI'm setting up a Linux server running Ubuntu to store a MySQL database.

It's important this server is secure as possible, as far as I'm aware my main concerns should be incoming DoS/DDoS attacks and unauthorized access to the server itself.

The database server only receives incoming data from one specific IP (101.432.XX.XX), on port 3000. I only want this server to be able to receive incoming requests from this IP, as well as prevent the server from making any outgoing requests.

I'd like to know:

1. What is the best way to prevent my database server from making outgoing requests and receiving incoming requests solely from 101.432.XX.XX? Would closing all ports ex. 3000 be helpful in achieving this?
2. Are there any other additions to the linux environment that can boost security? I've taken very basic steps to secure my phpmyadmin portal (linked to the MySQL database), such as restricting access to solely my personal IP address.
   To access the database server requires the SSH key (which itself is password protected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For closing all unwanted incoming and outgoing connections, you can use `iptables` as a firewall to do the job, here is an example:

```
# To make sure that you have ssh access to the server
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 101.432.XX.XX --dport 22   -j ACCEPT
# Allowing only your ip to connect to the server via specific port
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 101.432.XX.XX --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
# Drop any other requests
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -j DROP
```

That was just an example, you can almost do what ever you want with `iptables` for security.

For protecting your server against `DoS/DDoS`, I would recommend `csf` as a firewall tool, it can provide you a good protection against wide types of attacks, for more info about `csf` check this: https://download.configserver.com/csf/readme.txt

Answer (score 3):

Some installations also offer a tool for "hardening" the db:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

This steps you through setting a new root password, removing anonymous users, disallowing remote root login, and more.